# finding out how many queued tasks are in pool

Tags: java

How can I know how many tasks are in the queue,
Beside taking a memory(?) dump ?
It seems that even after running for more than 5000 tasks, the count is still on 5000.

```
WARN  c.p.c.e.ExceptionHandler - Error id is 1. General exception. URL: http://<url>, exception is: Executor [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@number[Running, pool size = 3, active threads = 3, queued tasks = 5000, completed tasks = 43869]] did not accept task: org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1@number
```

Comment: Just looking at the message I would guess that the queue has a max size of 5000, so before adding another task you need to allow one of the existing ones to finish. Perhaps configuring the pool to use more than 3 threads could help.

Comment: one could guess 5000 as well, but after 10,000 tasks and the queue has not yet decreased and still remains 5K, one could ask the question above "How can I know how many tasks are in the queue" - is there an easy way to know that ?

Comment: Well, "queued tasks = 5000" says it in plain text. As the error says that the queue is full and it has 5000 tasks in queue the max queue size is 5000. Right? You don't really need to know that though. What you need to know is that the number of workers (3) cannot keep up with the rate in which you are adding new tasks.You can also see that work is being done as 43869 tasks have been completed.